# Error when converting Python script to a package: <star.cli.CLI object at ...>

Tags: python, package, exe

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to convert my Python script into a package. The script works perfectly when executed as a Python file or when creating a standalone executable using PyInstaller. However, when I convert it into a package and run it, I get the following message at the end of every command:

> <star.cli.CLI object at 0x0000021E51E22C50>

### Project Structure:

```
(root)/
├─ env/
├─ src/
│  ├─ star
│     ├─ __init__.py
│     ├─ __main__.py
|     ├─ cli.py
|     ├─ version.py
├─ .gitignore
├─ README.md
├─ setup.py
```

### Code

```py
# cli.py

import os
import json
import argparse
from console import Console
from .version import __version__


console = Console()

class CLI:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.config = {}

        # Command Line Argument
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Star - Command Line Tool")
        self.parser.add_argument("script", metavar="script", nargs="?", default=None, help="Name of the script to run")
        self.parser.add_argument("-v", "--version", action="store_true", help="Display the version of Star")
        self.parser.add_argument("-l", "--list", action="store_true", help="List all available scripts", default=False)

        self.args = self.parser.parse_args()
        self.read_config_file()

        # Check for version flag
        if self.args.version:
            self.display_version()
        elif self.args.list or self.args.script is None:
            self.display_script_list()
        else:
            self.run_script(self.args.script)


    def read_config_file(self) -> None:
        """Read the configuration file."""
        file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "star.json")
        with open(file_path, "r") as file:
            self.config = json.loads(file.read())


    def display_version(self) -> None:
        """Display the version of Star."""
        print(f"Star CLI - Version {__version__}")

    
    def display_script_list(self) -> None:
        """Display a list of all commands in the star.json file."""
        script_list = self.config.get("scripts", {}).keys()
        if script_list:
            console.secondary("Available scripts:")
            for script_name in script_list:
                print(f" - {script_name}")
        else:
            console.secondary("No scripts found in star.json")


    def run_script(self, script_name: str) -> None:
        """Run the specified script."""
        try:
            scripts = self.config["scripts"].get(script_name)

            if isinstance(scripts, str):
                # Display the command.
                console.secondary(f"$ {scripts}")

                # Run the single command in the terminal.
                os.system(scripts)
            elif isinstance(scripts, list):
                # Display the commands.
                console.secondary(f"$ {' && '.join(scripts)}")

                # Run the multiple commands in the terminal.
                for script in scripts:
                    os.system(script)
            else:
                console.error("error", end=" ")
                print("Cannot convert an unknown type to a primitive value")
        except KeyError:
            console.error("error", end=" ")
            print(f"Command \"{script_name}\" not found.")
```

```py
# version.py

__version__ = "0.1.0"
```

```py
# __main__.py

from .cli import CLI


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CLI()
```

```py
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup
from src.star.version import __version__


setup(
    name="python-star",
    version=__version__,
    license="MIT",
    description="A command-line tool for simplifying project setup and development tasks.",
    long_description=open("README.md").read(),  # Make sure to create a README.md file
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=["star"],
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "star=star.__main__:CLI",
        ],
    },
    keywords=[
        "CLI",
        "project setup",
        "testing",
        "development",
        "automation",
        "scripting",
        "workflow",
        "convenience",
        "productivity",
        "deployment",
        "utility",
        "developer tool",
        "single command",
    ],
    install_requires=[
        "console-py==0.1.3",
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

### Environment:

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Python Version: 3.11.4
- PyInstaller Version: 5.13.0

### Expected Output:

I expect the package to behave the same way as when executing the script directly or when using PyInstaller to create a standalone executable. The unwanted message <star.cli.CLI object at ...> should not be displayed after each command.

### Additional Information:

- I have already tried implementing `__str__` and `__repr__` methods in my `CLI` class, and they seem to be working.
- I'm using the `console-py` package with version `0.1.3` as a dependency.
- The behavior persists even after implementing `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.

> Any other relevant information or specific details about your attempts to resolve the issue.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A- Try to reinstall package using pip install -e

B- Try to verify endpoint

> entry_points={
> "console_scripts": [
> "star=star.**main**:CLI.run_script",  # Specify the callable directly
> ], }

Comment: This is not working. I am try but throw error `TypeError: CLI.run_script() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'script_name'`